# Webservices for Spring 2.5.5

Tags: web-services

I have web application designed using spring 2.5.5 MVC, JBoss server. I want to expose my spring services (like add/update User, comments, documents, etc.) using WebService for EAI. Requirement is like any third-party application should be able to perform operations in my web application after authentication/authorization.
I have novice knowledge of SOAP (Axis2) and REST (Jersey), however i am not sure which will be best suited for my application.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

We are using Spring 3.0 actually. But former using Axis2 with Spring 2.5.x. 
You might review our stack at http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings the axis.
We simply integrated the regular Axis2 configuration into the web.xml and build a Facade to load the spring beans into the Axis enables Web-Service and forward the calls to the Spring enabled context that way.
Comparable to https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/openmeetings/trunk/singlewebapp/src/org/openmeetings/axis/services/FileWebServiceFacade.java

It is not the perfect solution, the Axis2 documentation also contains other ways to load the Spring context in the Web-Service enabled class, however it was never possible to make that work stable so we decided for this workaround.